# Use Iperf version 2 in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, iperf

My app requirment is to measure the throuput so want to use iperf 2 in that which is the requirment, but it is not available for objective c. so is it possible use this iperf2 library into my app to measure the tput? if yes then any lead will be appreciable.

Comment: Did you find any solution?